# 1 Biased Coin and 1 Fair Coin, probability of 2 Heads?

Tags: probability

You have 1 fair coin and 1 coin with 2 heads. Given that the first flip was a heads what is the probability of getting another heads?

My Answer: P(2H|F=H) = P(2H|F=H, Biased Coin)*P(Biased Coin) + P(2H|F=H, Unbiased Coin)*P(Unbiased Coin) = 0.5 + 0.25 = 0.75. In my equation, F refers to the First Throw. But the answer is supposed to be 5/6 and I can't seem to understand how.

**Edit**: From Arthurs comment I get the following, however, I dont know if this is the correct method, despite getting the correct answer:

P(Biased|F=H) = 2/3.

P(2H|F=H) = P(2H|(Biased|F=H))*P(Biased|F=H) + P(2H|(Unbiased|F=H))*P(Unbiased|F=H) = (1*2/3) + (1/2 * 2/3) = 5/6.

Thank You

Comment: Is it random (and unknown) which coin was flipped first?

Comment: @Arthur Yes. There is no information about that.

Comment: I think this is the biggest thing you've missed: Given that the first toss was a head, what is the proability that the first coin was the biased one?

Comment: @Arthur Could you please check the edit to my question.

Comment: @Jojo, yes, although that should be $P(2H\mid\text{ Biased} \cap F=H)$ and so forth.

Comment: Are you flipping the same coin twice, or flipping one then the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first flip was a head.

The $3$ heads have equal probabilities to be the head that appeared at the first flip.

$2$ of the $3$ heads have another head as other side.

$1$ of the $3$ heads has tail as other side.

So there is a chance of $\frac23.1+\frac13.\frac12=\frac56$ of throwing a second head with that coin.

Comment: Very intuitive answer. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help, and indeed cherish your intuition in maths.

Comment: Does this assume that the same coin is flipped twice, or that one coin is flipped and then the other? I'm getting a different answer when I assume that latter, but the question is ambiguous.

Comment: It assumes that the same coin was flipped twice.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a conditioning in your formula.
Let the event of choosing biased coin be B and fair be F.
Getting heads on second toss be 2H and on first toss 1H.
You want to calculate the probability of getting heads on second throw given that you it landed heads on first throw, which is

P(2H/1H) = P(2H/1H,F)P(F/1H) + P(2H/1H,B)P(B/1H)

To evaluate P(F/1H) and P(B/1H) use bayes rue.

P(F/1H) = P(1H/F)*P(F)/P(1H) = 0.5*0.5/(0.5*0.5 + 1*0.5) = 1/3

P(B/1H) = 2/3

P(1H) = P(1H/F)P(F) + P(1H/B)P(B)

P(2H/1H,F) = 0.5 and P(2H/1H,B) = 1
Therefore, P(2H/1H) = 0.5*(1/3) + 1*(2/3) = 5/6