# 1 Fair Coin, 1 Biased Coin. Keep getting heads. How many flips until probability of it being fair < 0.1

Tags: probability

This is a very challenging problem of which I'm stuck.

I have a fair coin with a probability of getting head as 0.5, and a bias coin with probability of getting head as 0.8

I grab a coin and I keep flipping it, and I keep getting heads. How many flips will it take for the probability of the coin being fair to drop < 0.1

---

Let our notation be:

- P(1H) = Probability of getting heads in first flip
- P(2H|1H) = Probability of getting heads on first flip, and heads on second flip
- P(F) = Probability of it being a fair coin
- P(B) = Probability of it being biased coin

I know that P(1H) = 0.5*0.5 + 0.5*0.8 = 0.65

P(F|1H) = Probability of first coin being fair if i got heads on first flip = P(1H|F)*P(F) / P(H) = (0.5*0.5)/0.65 = 0.3846

P(B|1H) = (0.8*0.5)/0.65 0.6154 given same calculations

P(2H|1H) = P(2H|1H, F|1H)*P(F|1H) + P(2H|1H, B|1H)*P(B|1H) = 
0.5*0.3846 + 0.8*0.6154 = 0.6846

P(F|(2H|1H)) = P(2H|1H, F)*P(F) / P(2H|1H) = 0.5*0.5 / 0.6846 = 0.3652

So I know the probability of getting a fair coin with two flips is as follows

But i could keep going, and this expression would get more and more complicated. How on earth do i solve this?

Comment: Please format your questions so that they are read-friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first find P(Fair | n Heads) = $P(F|nH)$, which can be written as $$P(F|nH) = \frac{P(nH|F)P(F)}{P(nH)} = \frac{(0.5)^n(0.5)}{(0.5)^n(0.5)+(0.8)^n(0.5)}$$
This should be < 0.1, and it it achieved when
$$9 < (\frac{8}{5})^n$$
which is satisfied first when $ n = 5 $.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that P(2H) = 0.5*0.5*0.5 + 0.8*0.8*0.5. I can't understand why this is the case.

Comment: Does this mean this expression i wrote above is wrong???

P(2H|1H) = P(2H|1H, F|1H)*P(F|1H) + P(2H|1H, B|1H)*P(B|1H) 

Is this then supposed to be 
P(2H|1H) = P(2H|1H, F)*P(F) + P(2H|1H, B)*P(B) 

Please explain why its like this and not like what i wrote

Comment: You have two ways of getting 2 heads, either you have biased or fair coin. That is $P(2H) = P(2H|F)P(F) + P(2H|B)P(B)$

Comment: Okay, however take a look at this question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481433/1-biased-coin-and-1-fair-coin-probability-of-2-heads?rq=1

They say that P(2H/1H) = P(2H/1H,F)P(F/1H) + P(2H/1H,B)P(B/1H)

Comment: First of all, one should use the following notation while describing the given events: $P(A|B) = P(A,C| B) + P(A,C'|B)$, which in turn equals to $P(A|B,C)P(C|B) + P(A|B,C')P(C'|B)$, i.e. keep the occured event after | sign to impede any confusion.

Comment: exactly, so shouldn't it be P(2H|(F|H))P(F|H) and not P(2H|F)P(F)

Comment: That means in the answer to question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481433/1-biased-coin-and-1-fair-coin-probability-of-2-heads?rq=1

 P(2H/1H) = 0.5*(1/3) + 1*(2/3) = 5/6

should be

(0.5^2)(0.5) + (1^2)(0.5)

Comment: P(2H|1H) = P(2H|1H, F)*P(F|1H) + P(2H|1H, B)*P(B|1H). Keep the occured event everywhere after | sign, you don't need multiple | signs.

Comment: Sir please..i want to know:

When to write this expression:

P(2H|1H) = P(2H|1H, F)*P(F|1H) + P(2H|1H, B)*P(B|1H)

and when to write

P(2H)=P(2H|F)P(F)+P(2H|B)P(B)

They both yield two different results. Here P(2H) is the same as P(2H|1H)